# Swift Contains Array Error: Missing argument label 'where:' in call

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a contains statement to determine if a UserDefaults array has a certain value in it. However, I keep getting the error `Missing argument label 'where:' in call`. I have tried looking for the reason, but no one else seems to have this problem. Any help is appreciated, and heres the code:

```
var items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "purchasedItems")

if items!.contains(1) {
    print("works!")
}
```

Thanks! :D

Comment: Try `if items?.contains(where: {$0 == 1}){`

Comment: What is `items` supposed to be? Array of `Int`? Array of dictionary? The complier doesn't know. We don't either. (Optional down)cast the array to the expected type. @LeoDabus `$0` is `Any` and has no clue if it's equatable

Comment: @vadian that’s true I am on my mobile and didn’t pay to much attention to it.

Comment: It's an int, would that mean $0 wouldn’t work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading. `array(forKey` returns `[Any]?` so you have to cast the object to the expected type to ensure that the type conforms to `Equatable`

```
if let items = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "purchasedItems") as? [Int] {
    if items.contains(1) {
       print("works!")
    }
}
```

Comment: weird, I'm having the same type for both elements and yet, it just keeps bugging me.